# I have two questions! The one is printing and another is zoom

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wanted to make a printing function on the picture. so these are the codes

```
<li>
<a href="#" class="print_btn"><img src="../picture/util_print.gif" alt=""></a>
</li>
```

**On the jquery, I coded this below**

```
$(".print_btn").on("click",function(){
     window.print();
     return false;
})
```

But Nothing happens and I don't know why. 
Also for the zoom in and out code

```
<ul id="zoom">
<li>
<a href="#" class="zoom_in"><img src="../picture/util_zoom_2.gif" alt=""></a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#" class="zoom_out"><img src="../picture/util_zoom_4.gif" alt=""></a>
</li>
</ul>
```

On the javascript code, I typed

```
var base=100;
var mybody=$("body");

$("#zoom a").on("click",function() {
    var zNum=$("#zoom a").index(this);
    if (zNum == 0) {
        base += 10;
    } else if (zNum == 1) { //100%
        base = 100;
    } else {
        base-=10;
    }
    mybody
    .css("overflow-x","auto")
    .css("transform-origin","0 0")
    .css("transform","scale("+base/100+")")
    .css("zoom",base+"%");
    return false; 
});
```

Nothing happens and I still don't understand why.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Print Solution use this code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('img').click(function() {
            window.print();
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>

<div><img src="#" onclick="window.print(); return false;"></div>
```

For zoom solution use this code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>abc</div>
<button type="button" id="zoom-in">zoom in</button>
<button type="button" id="zoom-out">zoom out</button>
<script>
    $('#zoom-in').click(function() {
        updateZoom(0.1);
    });

    $('#zoom-out').click(function() {
        updateZoom(-0.1);
    });


    zoomLevel = 1;

    var updateZoom = function(zoom) {
        zoomLevel += zoom;
        $('body').css({
            zoom: zoomLevel,
            '-moz-transform': 'scale(' + zoomLevel + ')'
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this below code it may help you to solve the issue.

```js
$(".print_btn img").click(function(){
    window.print();
    return false;
  });

$("#zoom a").on("click",function() {
    var base=100;
    var mybody=$("body");
    var zNum=$("#zoom a").index(this);
    if (zNum == 0) {
        base += 10;
    } else if (zNum == 1) { //100%
    } else {
        base-=10;
    }
     mybody
    .css("overflow-x","auto")
    .css("transform-origin","0 0")
    .css("transform","scale("+base/100+")")
    .css("zoom",base+"%");
    return false;
});
```

```css
.print_btn img{height : 100px; width : 100px;}

#zoom a img {height : 100px; width : 100px;}
li {list-style-type : none;}
#zoom a{text-decoration :  none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
<a href="#" class="print_btn"><img src="https://www.sdc.com.jo/arabic/images/printer-icon.png" alt=""></a>
</li>


<ul id="zoom">
<li>
<a href="#" class="zoom_in"><img src="http://www.pngimagesfree.com/Globe/3d-Globe-png.png" alt=""> Zoom In :)</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#" class="zoom_out"><img src="http://a826.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/068/Purple/v4/e8/d6/1e/e8d61ef2-ea99-2562-b41e-fae6e92dd838/mzl.wdxfapbe.png" alt=""> Zoom Out :(</a>
</li>
</ul>
```